# Where is the Air Valve on a swiss made ark hollow reverse fork?

Tags: fork, suspension, air-spring

My fork is swiss made ark hollow reverse type, air type.

One problem it does not have an air valve for the air.  Where is the valve ?

Answer (score 10):

Remove the top panel on the left side of the fork to expose the valve.

[image]
[image]